# Manual integration by parts

Tags: calculus

How?

$\int\frac{x^2}{x^{2}+1} dx
\\ \mbox{ Let } dv= x^2dx,u=\frac{x^2}{x^{2}+1},v=\frac{x^3}{3}, du=arctan\left(x\right)dx \\ =\frac{x^3}{3}\frac{x^2}{x^{2}+1}-\int\frac{x^3}{3}arctan\left(x\right)dx$

What now? Can be By parts or not

Edit.
Ok My bad

Comment: You do not need integration by parts here.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you need integration by parts? The integral is just:

$$\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}dx = \int 1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{x^2}{x^{2}+1} dx=\int\frac{x^2+1-1}{x^{2}+1}dx=\int 1dx-\int\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}dx=x-\arctan x+C.$$